# Is it a good practice use Django integrated web server behind a proxy?

Tags: django, docker, security, docker-compose

I implement a Django website behind a NGINX configured as reverse proxy which serve also the static for Django when it is out of debug mode, all this is in a docker-compose app.

I know by read the Django docs they do not recommend to use integrated web server in a production environment (and it is not at the moment), put it behind a reverse proxy is acceptable to avoid security issue or it is the same as expose it directly?

If it is not an acceptable solution, could you suggest any implementation to not use the Django integrated web server?

Consider that the container structure like the following:

[image]

- Proxy is the NGINX Official image
- www1 & www2 are Python3 Official image with Django installed as described [here.](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/)
- database is the Postgres Official image.

Only the Proxy container is exposed to the external world.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get my answer, I gonna use gunicorn instead the integrated Django web browser.

I had use documentation present [here](https://django-best-practices.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment/servers.html) That describe how to configure gunicorn and nginx on the same host, but using http instead linux socket, instead the command to run the Django integrate web server I have just to run gunicorn like this:

```
gunicorn --workers=4 --bind=0.0.0.0:9000 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - --log-level debug myapp.wsgi:application
```

with the previous command I also get logs managed by container.

Off course I also add gunicorn in the requirement file.

I hope this question will help also some one else.